# Better way to check if the data already exists and insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

Hi all I have the following SQL Server 2008 script that will check if a row already exists in `Table A` and if it doesn't insert the data from `Table B`.

This was working nicely until `Table A` started to fill up with a lot of data. We currently have 30 million rows in this table and this will continue to grow to a predicated 70 million rows.

The problem if this is taking far too long and is affecting other processes. Just wondering if there is a better way to check if a row already exists in a table. Just to add as well this is all done using an SSIS.

Script:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE A ([recordID],Field 1, Field2, Field 3, Field 4, Field 5) 
    SELECT 
        [TABLE B].[recordID],[TABLE B].[Field 1], [TABLE B].[Field2], 
        [TABLE B].[Field 3], [TABLE B].[Field 4], [TABLE B].[Field 5] 
    FROM TABLE B AS TABLE B 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE A AS TABLE A ON [TABLE B].[recordID] = [TABLE A].[recordID] 
    WHERE [TABLE A].[recordID] IS NULL
```

Comment: Make sure the proper nonclustered indices are in place - most notably on the `RecordID` column in both `Table A` and `Table B` (since this in your JOIN condition)

Comment: I already have a index for RecordID on both Table A and Table B. However i've got them set to being clustered, should they be nonclustered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the the Merge command:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this will be faster, but worth a try:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE A ([recordID],Field 1, Field2, Field 3, Field 4, Field 5)

SELECT [TABLE B].[recordID],[TABLE B].[Field 1], [TABLE B].[Field2], [TABLE B].[Field 3], [TABLE B].[Field 4], [TABLE B].[Field 5] 
FROM TABLE B 
where b.recordID not in 
     (select recordID from A)
```

Comment: +1 - `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` is much faster than a `LEFT JOIN` for most use cases.

Answer (score 0):

1. If it is clustered Index, and the newly added RecordId is not incremental, then lot of page spilt is expected to happen. Make sure to set optimal Fill Factor.
2. Find what operation takes time, then it will be simple to address. If it Searching is taking time or inserting is taking time?